# Study of the class of functions satisfying null-IVP

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, gn.general-topology, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

$\mathcal{N}_u$ : Class of all uncountable Lebesgue-null set i.e all uncountable sets having Lebesgue outer measure $0$.

> Let $f:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$ be a function with the following property :
> $\forall p\neq q\in\Bbb{R}$ with $f(p) \neq f(q) $ and $\forall
>  N\in\mathcal{N_u}$ between $f(p) $ and $f(q) $ there exists
> $N_1\in\mathcal{N_u}$ in between $p$ and $q$ such that $f(N_1) \subset N$

If such property doesn't have a name,call this property $\textbf{NIVP}$ : Null Intermediate Value Property.

---

Goal :

1. How can we define the function $f$ satisfying $\textbf{NIVP}$ locally?
2. What is the relation between Darboux function and function satisfying $\textbf{NIVP}$?
3. Does every function satisfying $\textbf{CIVP}$ has $\textbf{NIVP}$ ? (obvious)
4. Does $\textbf{NIVP}+$ first baire class coincide with the class of Darboux functions?
5. Is the set of all points where $f$ has $\textbf{NIVP}$ a $G_{\delta}$ set?

Can someone help me to study the class $\textbf{NIVP}$?

Can you provide any book or related research paper for further development?

Note: If $f$ satisfy $\textbf{NIVP}$ for $N, N_1$ both are Cantor sets, then we call $f$ , a function having $\textbf{CIVP}$.

Comment: One should not ask multiple questions in one post, and this is not a good strategy for the asker either.